# using form_tag undefined method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with the form_tag in rails. It is telling me there is an undefined method or local variable called sendrequest. However I have defined this in my controller. what am I missing? (PS I'm new  to rails so if you see any bad  syntax please let me know). Thanks!

Here is my home.html.erb:

```
<% form_tag sendrequest %>
    <%=check_box_tag "friendids[]", 12345 %> 
    <%=check_box_tag "friendids[]", 67890 %>
    <%= submit_tag "send requests"%>
<% end_form_tag %>
```

In my game_pages_controller I have an empty function for sendrequest right now.

```
def sendrequest
end
```

my routes just routes game pages to home.

```
root to: 'game_pages#home'
match '/home', to: 'game_pages#home'
```

The purpose of the checkboxes is to get a list of a user's friends that he wants to select. However I don't need to add this to a database, that's why I don't have any friend's model. I'd like to use some javascript such that submitting the form will iterate through the friendsids and do some function with them. For that reason I don't need to keep a friends model and the checkboxes don't actually update any models for the current user.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the form to go to the `sendrequest` action, you need to set up your routes and use that in the form.

```
# routes
match '/sendrequest' => 'game_pages#sendrequest', as: :sendrequest

# view
<%= form_tag sendrequest_path do %>
```

This is how it should be set up.  You match the url in the view to an action in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a method from your controller in your views you have to tell the view context to include it using `helper_method` in your Controller.

```
class GamePagesController < ApplicationController

  def sendrequest
  end
  helper_method :sendrequest
end
```

Unless your actually using that method in your controller, then it really belongs in a helper module, in which case it will automatically be included in the view context.

Also there are some more issues with your code.

```
<%= form_tag sendrequest do %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'friendids[]', 12345 %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'friendids[]', 67890 %>
  <%= submit_tag 'send requests' %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, the form tag needs to wrapped in an output erb not a regular erb, otherwise it will not output your code to the buffer. And there is no end_form_tag, instead you use the normal ruby do/end block syntax. Anything within that block will be wrapped in the form tags.

Comment: this will probably fix the error but not the real issue.  the real issue is setting up a route that should go to the sendrequest action.

Comment: @jvnill Why would that be a better solution?

Comment: forgot to indent the block, the code corrections are there now. And yes, there needs to be a route. form_tag takes a path (the action) which should pass through to a route when the form is submitted.

Comment: @Cluster Thanks for cleaning up my code and explaining a solution. However I'm going to accept jvnill's because it seems to be the more correct solution. Thanks for your help as well though!